# Rosetta Arm64 M1 libxcrun.dylib.aot fail

Tags: macos, terminal, apple-m1, rosetta

so I am having issues with Rosetta, and whenever I want to do any install or use a makefile, I get this error:

> `rosetta error: /var/db/oah/c642c66595f5050af26db8f86497ea83caff7cea5a9bcb2361ffa81d0e090b58/e3dffc0922c5d9c2da11a427e8274cb75a79f184276373ffc39b65cfa67f4141/libxcrun.dylib.aot: attachment of code signature supplement failed: 1`

I am using the newest MacBook Pro M1. Installed using the softwareupdate --install-rosetta.
I can't find anything about it using google, what could be wrong here?

Comment: any update on how this was resolved? if this was resolved?

Comment: Facing similar issue, found any solution?